# Overlaying Sentinel-1 collection scenes on Google Earth platform

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-1, sar

I'm new to GEE and I need to create  some code to estimate Soil Surface Moisture (SSM) in Google Engine. However, when generating the image on the map, the product has an issue with overlapping scenes from the collection used (COPERNICUS/S1_GRD), as can be seen in the figure below.

[image: overlapping scenes]

How can I fix this?

```
var s1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
  .select('VV')
  .map(function(image) {
    return image.clip(table)
  })

var mosaic = s1.mosaic()

Map.addLayer(mosaic, {min: -18, max: -2, palette: 'red, blue, yellow, green'}, 'VV')

var minMax = s1.reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax())
var SSMCollection = s1.map(function(image) {
  var SSM = image.expression(
    '(sigma - min) / (max - min)', {
      'sigma': image.select('VV'),
      'min': minMax.select(ee.String('VV').cat('_min')),
      'max': minMax.select(ee.String('VV').cat('_max'))
    }).rename('SSM')
  return SSM
})

var SSM_Mean = SSMCollection.mean()

Map.addLayer(SSM_Mean, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['e53935', 'f4511e', 'fb8c00', 'ffb300', 'fdd835', 'c0ca33', '7cb342', '43a047', '00897b', '006266', '0a3d62']}, 'Soil Moisture')
Map.centerObject(roi, 10)
```

Link to the code (https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/d773e84262d5e2f85e67565ab03a85ce)

Comment: There are noise at the edge of the S1 scenes. You can mask it out based on the angle band: `image.updateMask(angle.gt(30.88).and(angle.lt(45.35)))`. Unfortunately, there are not one set of angles that works everywhere, so you might need to tweak it based on your area.